# Load Magento 2 static Block content in external website php file

Tags: magento2, php, static-block, external

I have a requirement like below.

There is a website which is running in production mode in one server.

That has some static blocks.

A block is created with some content(Ex:Block_Id: **sample_block**).

Here my question is I need to get the content of that block and load it in external PHP file, which is in different server.

Is this can be achieved in any way. please suggest me.

Comment: Yes @RohanHapani, that php file may be in different server, or can be in localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento REST APIs to get static block content.

Comment: can you pls post an answer if possible.